Help on installation required: "The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later."
I keep running into the same error. Please help!
I installed Drupal 10 (latest)
I can access Durpal via https://192.168.100.135/ and I can log in.
Next followed these steps:
https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal/
My install command looks like this:
cv core:install --cms-base-url="https://192.168.100.135/" --db="mysql://civicrm_user:mypassword@localhost:3306/civicrm_db"
It seems to run alright and in Drupal's admin panel I can see the modules CiviCRM Core and CiviCRM Theme; neither of which are activated.
Here's the catch: every time I activated them I get a white screen saying:
The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.
What can I do?

Generally, that "website encountered an unexpected error" message is connected to some deeper error that you need to find and account for. Check the various log locations and track it down. It could be something very simple or something very complicated, but it is impossible to know without knowing the actual underlying error. Most of the time the php server log is the most useful, but it depends on how your server is setup to log.
